# Track multiple subdomains with Google Analytics

Tags: subdomain, wildcard-subdomain

I need to track multiple subdomains that are created dynamically. I run a SaaS business where users can create their own site name when signing up for my service. For example, if John Doe signs up for my service, he can create his own subdomain something like jdoe.example.com. If Jane Doe signs up for my service, they can create a subdomain like janedoe.example.com, and so on. So basically, each time a new customer signs up for my service, they create their own personalized subdomain. What I am trying to do is track the process users go through from trial account signup to conversion (they become paying subscribers). This is the process users go through when signing up for a trial account and converting to a subscriber:

1) All users sign up on the TLD of www.example.com

2) When they click the "Signup" button on www.example.com, they are redirected to account.example.com where they create a custom subdomain (e.g. janedoe.example.com). When they click on the "Save" button on account.example.com they are redirected to their account login screen at janedoe.example.com/login.

3) Users sign up as a paying customer/subscriber on the subdomain they created earlier (e.g. janedoe.example.com).

**My question is: How can I track users as they go from www.example.com > account.example.com > whatever subdomain they create**? Normally, I'd create a profile for each subdomain, but since subdomains are created on-the-fly and there are hundreds of them, creating a profile for each subdomain won't work, especially since Google Analytics only allows 50 profiles. **Basically, I need to track users across one TLD and two subdomains. Can I modify the Google Analytics tracking code snippet that would allow this? Is there a wildcard I can use since domains are created dynamically?**

Comment: Sub-domain tracking is done simply by setting your tracker `cookieDomain` to `auto` when it is being created `ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');`. When this is done, as long as you have the same tracking code on all subdomains, then all sessions across the subdomains are automatic. You'll also need to make sure you add your TLD (`example.com`) to the referral exclusion list.

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I added the TLD to the referral exclusion list under Properties. My other question is this: Now that I have subdomain tracking implemented, I need to create 3 views. I need one view to track the subdomain only, another view to track TLD traffic only, and a third view that tracks both TLD and subdomain traffic. Subdomains are created dynamically. Can I use a wildcard in a filter to accommodate this? What is the best way to create filters for each view?